# Access property object (for replacing setter method)

Tags: python, properties

Consider the following code taken from [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties)

```
class test:
    _x = 10
    def getx(self): return self._x
    def setx(self, value): self._x = value
    x = property(getx, setx)
```

as already explained in many other questions, this is 100% equivalent to

```
class test:    

    _x = 10

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, val):
        self._x = val
```

I would like to access **the property** `x` (and not the `int` in `_x`) in order to change the value of `x.setter`.

However doing `type(test().x)` returns `int` rather than `property` indicating that what `test().x` returns is `_x` and not the property `x`. Indeed, trying to do access `test().x.setter` returns a `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'setter'`.

I understand that 99.9% of the time, when someone does `test().x` he wants to access the value associated with the property `x`. This is exactly what properties are meant for.

However, how can I do in that 0.01% of the times when I want to access the `property` object rather than the value returned by the `getter`?

Comment: Probably not since the decorators are applied during reading and not retained during runtime.

Comment: It's `type(test()).x`; get the underlying type of the instance, *then* get the `property`-valued attribute.

Comment: but the same holds true for the first example where decorators are not used. Moreover, if I understood `property` correctly, `@x.setter` is using the `setter` method of the `property` object `x` as decorator for the following method. So, at least in that context, `x` is not the value returned by the `getter` but it's the `property` itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is a *class* attribute, whose `__get__` method receives a reference to the object when invoked on an instance of the class. You need to get a reference to the class first, then you can get the actual `property` object without invoking the getter.

```
>>> t = test()
>>> t.x
10
>>> type(t).x
<property object at ....>
```

Comment: The key is indeed that properties are *class* attributes. Thank you very much, not everything is much clearer. PS: trying your answer I just discovered that 'property' object attribute 'setter' are read-only. This makes my reason to access the property pointless, but this is another topic...

Comment: It is read-only, but the way `x.setter` works in the first example is to return a *new* `property` instance with the given setter. That's why the name of the decorated method needs to be the same as the existing property: so that the decorator assigns the new property to the name already in use.